# Python: calc n factorial only use call expressions, conditional expressions, and lambda expressions

Tags: python

This is an interesting question from online.
The full question is:

> To write a recursive function, we have always given it a name using a def or assignment statement so that we can refer to the function within its own body. In this question, your job is to define it recursively without giving it a name!

> Write an expression to complete the function **make_anonymous_factorial()**,which computes **n factorial** using only **call expressions, conditional expressions, and lambda expressions (no assignment or def statements)**. Note in particular that you are not allowed to use make_anonymous_factorial in your return expression. The sub and mul functions from the operator module are the only built-in functions required to solve this problem.
> e.g.
> >>> make_anonymous_factorial( )(5)
> 120

Here is my solution:

```
from operator import sub, mul

def make_anonymous_factorial():
    from functools import reduce
    return lambda n:reduce(mul, range(1, n + 1))
```

However, as the question described,**The sub and mul functions from the operator module are the only built-in functions required to solve this problem**, since I used reduce( ), I don't think it is a suitable answer.

Is there a better solution?

(The question is from cs61a summer 2020 HW03, Q6, and [here is the link](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs61a/su20/hw/hw03/). It's the last question which is on the bottom of the page.)

Comment: Could you post a link to the source? Or is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Sure. This is from cs61a summer 2020 HW03, Q6, and [here is the link](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/su20/hw/hw03/) It's the last question which is on the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the article Frank mentioned up to the point where it talks about a function getting itself as argument, I tried that ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5BCsMgFET3nmKWCtmEUii5TDCNUqn@Lz@6yOmtkXbZWQ3MG2byWV5Mt0eW1rxwAmcntrAgpMxScNRtQqpRqd15JPt2qyWmM3E9Vm@fHQ02arModIkrVQg62rTtFn7B19ECr2mCN0YP8tIvmy6wbwxA98XLzGbQCB4EFw@HeRSNUlkCFf3/i74b09oH)):

```
from operator import sub, mul

def make_anonymous_factorial():
    return (lambda f: lambda n: f(n, f))(
        lambda n, f: mul(n, f(sub(n, 1), f)) if n else 1
    )

print(make_anonymous_factorial()(5))
```

The innermost `lambda n, f:` is the real factorial computer, and it'll get itself as second argument. That is organized by the outer two lambdas. The `lambda n:` is the one I return, it calls the real factorial with `n` and itself.

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot! Maybe it'll take days for me to fully understand.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good explanation of the Y combinator.  Its example is writing factorial in Python!

https://lptk.github.io/programming/2019/10/15/simple-essence-y-combinator.html

Answer (score 1):

If lambda is OK, this code works:

```
f = lambda x: x * f(x - 1) if x > 1 else 1
# example
print(f(5)) # 120
```

Without assignment using reduce from functools:

```
from functools import reduce
print(reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, list(range(1, 5 + 1)))) # 120
```

Comment: That is correct .But assignment is not allowed in this question.

Comment: @Deler how about reduce? Look if its OK.

Comment: That is similar to my first-edition solution.But the question limits  the built-in functions to only mul and sub : "The sub and mul functions from the operator module are the only built-in functions required to solve this problem" (maybe you should read the question carefully)